# Associate a Public IP in an Azure Resource Group to a Web App?

Tags: powershell, azure, static-ip

I'm playing around with Azure Resource Groups.

I've created a group, and in it, I've created a web app.  (This is all just academic and I'll delete it all when I'm done leaning, so I don't mind sharing the data.)  The web app is located at http://woodswild.azurewebsites.net, and indeed you can go to that address and it will resolve (although there is nothing there, which is fine for now.)

Then, in the same resource group, I also created a Public IP Address that is static.

[image]

That all looks good (I think, anyway).  But in the Portal UI, I see that this IP is not associated to anything:

[image]

Aaannndd.... I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. I created the Public IP from within Azure PowerShell with this command:

```
New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -AllocationMethod Static -ResourceGroupName TestRG1 -ReverseFqdn woodswild.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com -Name woodswild.azurewebsites.net -Location "Central US" -DomainNameLabel woodswild
```

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603620.aspx) that explains the New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress command, there is no parameter to declare an association.  I'm not seeing a way to do it in the Portal UI, and I can't find any answers via Google.

What I'm hoping / wondering / assuming is that once this association is made, you could put the IP Address in a browser and it would resolve to the same place as http://woodswild.azurewebsites.net.

Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Public IP's are IaaS objects. The association is from NIC to Public IP not the other way around. That's why you can't see a way to associate an IP with anything.

My guess is that you're trying to associate an IP address so that you can have a custom domain associated. Instructions for that are here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/